# Auto complete folder entry for a text box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Without beating about the bush - `openFileDialog1` does not allow the selection of folders, and `folderBrowserDialog` is awful (and for my specific desires - doesn't allow manual entry for the sake of entering an admin share like `\\someserver\c$\somefolder`

So I wish to use a simple edit box to allow the user to type a path.  But I am wondering if there is any built in control or functionality available to a C# windows forms app that will auto-fill folders much like what happens when you type out paths in most file/folder select dialog boxes in Windows (7,8)

I want to explore options that might be available "out-of-the-box" before resorting to downloading third party code/plugins/addons to allow this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, those are built into the `TextBox` and `ComboBox` classes as [found here](http://codeskaters.blogspot.nl/2014/01/winforms-c-autocomplete-for-textbox-and.html):

```
textBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.FileSystem;
```

Comment: Thankyou.  I found this shortly after submitting my question.   I was going to supply an answer but you beat me to it :)  I will accept yours... in 8 minutes when it will let me.

Comment: its ok though it only does one folder at a time, though win7 explorer or run dialog box will suggest whole paths